# Where is the realization of getline c function in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4, getline, xcode4.3

I have searched through a lot of folders, but found definition only (in stdio.h) - not the realization.

Comment: On Mac OS X, it's not part of glibc but of the system's libc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the source code for the C library:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.12/stdio/getline-fbsd.c

Answer (score 1):

http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.12/stdio/getline-fbsd.c